# reactivex java creating a custom observer that emits events at some random time in the future

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

I am trying to figure out how to create an async observer and `trigger/emit` events at some time in the future without rebuilding the observable and the subscriber list.

Looking for something like:

```
MyAsyncObservable o = new MyAsyncObservable();

o.subscribe(s);
o.subscribe(s2);
while(scanner.hasNext()){
  o.emit(scanner.nextInt()); // emit T to subscribers.
}
```

Where `MyAsyncObservable` could just be a `Observable.fromAsync(emitter,buffermode)`

instead of

```
while(scanner.hasNext(){
  Observable<Integer> o = Observable.just(scanner.nextInt());
  o.subscribe(s);
  o.subscribe(s2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your observable is cold, just use .delay(); see f.e. this:

```
Observable.just("Hello!").delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

If it's a hot observable, just add a buffer (assuming you don't expect more than 10 emissions in 10 seconds:

```
Observable
  .just("Hello!")
  .onBackpressureBuffer(10)
  .delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Edit: Oh, I see - you want a `Subject` - Either `PublishSubject` or `BehaviorSubject`. Create them and feed them data via the usual onNext/onComplete/onError.

Comment: Not really looking for a delayed send. More about figuring out how to make a hot observable that will emit events based on some other object( open connection, user input, etc).

Comment: and that is what I was looking for! No idea why they burry this as the last topic on the rxjava documentation.

Comment: @JoseDiaz because it's a tool best used sparingly; it breaks backpressure, it breaks unsubscription notification, and it's too easy to fall into a rut using it on every occasion that is slightly different than the documentation. that said, you don't *need* to use it for this case, but it makes life easier.